# WKWebView backList sometimes becomes empty

Tags: ios, wkwebview

This is weird bug, sometimes going back (swiping back) in WKWebView removes `backForwardList.backList` items. Here's the flow:

1. Go to some url (push link on WKWebView)
2. Go back (swipe back)
3. WKWebView navigation fails, error can be caught in `didFailProvisionalNavigation`. Error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.MyDWebsite.com/m,
>   _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.MyDWebsite.com/m}

At this point (in `didFailProvisionalNavigation`) `webView.URL` is the one from witch user is going back, for example `www.MyDWebsite.com/m/Something` and `backForwardList.backList` is empty. Meanwhile `.fowardList` has one item, its the URL from which user is going back.

My question is why `.backList` is empty? I can't reload `webView.URL` because it is wrong one and I can not `.goBack()` because `.backList` is empty. As a result page is broken (does not load lazy images)

*Side question, does anyone know what could cause that -999 error?*